# Reemplazar salida de un for en python

Tags: python

hoy he empezado en python y tengo una duda, yo tengo este código:

```
for x in range(101):
print(x, end=" ")
```

Y quiero que al imprimir un número nuevo solo se muestre ese número, es decir, que el número nuevo creado por el bucle reemplace al anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un [**`CR`**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retorno_de_carro) para regresar al principio de la línea

```
import time
for x in range(101):  
    print(x, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Le añades un sleep para que no pase por todo el loop casi de inmediato

Comment: Lo que yo busco es que se reemplace el anterior por el siguiente, no que se muestren todos.

Comment: Eso hace en mi powershell.. Estás en Linux?

Comment: No, lo ejecuto en el propio python

Comment: Imagino que te refieres al IDLE... Pues buscando por internet me parece que no hay forma de limpiar la pantalla en el IDLE; solo en la terminal del sistema (cmd, pwshell, bash, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta probar con el siguiente código

```
for x in range(101):
    print(end="")

print (x)
```

> Output: 100

Te muestra de una vez al número que quieres llegar sin mostrarte todos.

En tal caso, prueba este y observa el resultado:

```
for x in range(101):
    print("El numero es: ",x)

print ("El número final es:", x)
```

Comment: No, lo que yo quiero es que se muestren los números, es decir que se muestre el número y se reemplace por el siguiente.

Comment: Utiliza el código de @DannyTalent pero el time.sleep, bájalo a 0.1 y saldrá lo que quieres.

Comment: Observa la última edición que hice como respuesta. Prueba si te funciona. @AarónRojasGutiérrez